# How to "watch" all contents of a dynamically created multi-dimension array in Visual Studio debug

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, debugging, pointers

I have a 2 dimension array created by `malloc`. Simplified code is like:

```
double **p = dmatrix(0, 50, 0, 50);
```

When debugging, I want to see the content for all the 51*51 members in one go.
I tried to use below in "watch":

```
p,51; //to show all the address for 1st dimension, but can't expand 2nd dimension. (only show 1st one)
p[0][0]; //to show the [0][0]
p[0],51; //to show all 51 members for p[0]
```

I hope to do something like:

```
p,51 51 //to show all the address for 1st dimension, while can also expand the 2nd dimension.
```

Any suggestions? I've tried the "memory" window but it's not intuitive..

Answer (score 0):

Just found one solution by myself. let's assume you have below pointer:

```
double ** p; // assume 51*51
```

then you can write below in Visual Studio debug watch:

```
(double(*)[51]) p[0],51
```

which will cast it into an array like below, and you can view all contents in one go.

```
double[51][51] p;
```

Similarly, we can apply it to 3 dimension pointers, just write like:

```
(double(*)[51][51]) p[0][0],51  //for 51*51*51
```